# My backend is not working , Can someone help figure out the issue with my code?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, math, sympy

[This is the output of Results.html [and the second image is the debug(console output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOMfU.png) I am building an web app in python3 , I am using flask and html , the app is suppose to receive any Mathematical problem from the user input, try to solve it and return the results in results.html, but the issue now is that every time  I enter a problem it keeps on returning "no solution found"

```
app.py


from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        problem = request.form['problem']
        # code to solve problem goes here
        return render_template('results.html')
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')


# Define function for solving problems
def solve_problem(problem_str):
    problem_str = problem_str.replace(" ", "")
    # Check if the problem has been solved before
    if problem_str in prev_problems:
        return prev_problems[problem_str]

    # Check if the problem is an equation
    if "=" in problem_str:
        # Parse the equation
        left, right = problem_str.split("=")
        expr = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(left) - sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(right)

        # Solve the equation
        solutions = sympy.solve(expr, sympy.symbols('x'))

        # If the left-hand side was not zero, add the right-hand side to the solutions
        if left != str(solutions[0]):
            solutions = [sol + sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(right) for sol in solutions]

    # Check if the problem is a system of equations
    elif 'system' in problem_str:
        eqns = problem_str.split(',')
        eqns = [sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(eqn) for eqn in eqns]
        vars = []
        for eqn in eqns:
            vars += list(eqn.free_symbols)
        vars = sorted(set(vars), key=lambda var: str(var))
        solutions = sympy.solve(eqns, vars)

    # Check if the problem is a polynomial equation
    elif 'polynomial' in problem_str:
        expr = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(problem_str.replace('polynomial', ''))
        solutions = sympy.roots(expr, multiple=True)
        
    # Check if the problem is a derivative
    elif 'derivative' in problem_str:
        expr, x, a = problem_str.split(',')
        expr = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(expr)
        a = float(a)
        solutions = sympy.diff(expr, sympy.symbols(x)).subs(sympy.symbols(x), a)

    # Check if the problem is an integral
    elif 'integral' in problem_str:
        expr, x, a, b = problem_str.split(',')
        expr = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(expr)
        a = float(a)
        b = float(b)
        solutions = sympy.integrate(expr, (sympy.symbols(x), a, b))
    
    # Check if the problem is a Fourier series
    elif 'fourier series' in problem_str:
        expr, x, a, b = problem_str.split(',')
        expr = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(expr)
        a = float(a)
        b = float(b)
        period = b - a
        fs = sympy.fourier_series(expr, (symbols(x), a, b))
        solutions = fs.truncate(n=5)

    # Check if the problem is a partial differential equation
    elif 'heat equation' in problem_str:
        x, y, t = symbols('x y t')
        u = sympy.Function('u')(x, y, t)
        k = symbols('k')
        eq = Eq(sympy.diff(u, t) - k*(sympy.diff(u, x, x) + sympy.diff(u, y, y)), 0)
        solutions = sympy.pde.pdsolve(eq)

    else:
        # Parse the problem into a SymPy expression
        expr = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(problem_str)

        # Solve the problem by simplifying the expression
        solutions = sympy.simplify(expr)


    # Check for additional functionality
    if 'sin' in problem_str or 'cos' in problem_str:
        solutions = sympy.solveset(expr, symbols('x'))
    elif 'tan' in problem_str:
        expr = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(problem_str)
        solutions = sympy.simplify(expr)
        
    elif 'limit' in problem_str:
        expr, x, a = problem_str.split(',')
        expr = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(expr)
        a = float(a)
        solutions = sympy.limit(expr, symbols(x), a)
        
    elif 'second derivative' in problem_str:
        expr = problem_str.replace('second derivative of ', '')
        expr = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(expr)
        solutions = sympy.diff(expr, symbols('x'), 2)
        
    elif 'heat equation' in problem_str:
        u = sympy.Function('u')(symbols('x'), symbols('y'))
        eq = sympy.Eq(sympy.diff(u, symbols('x'), symbols('x')) + sympy.diff(u, symbols('y'), symbols('y')), 0)
        solutions = sympy.pde.pdsolve(eq)
        
    # Check if the problem is a second-order differential equation
    elif 'second order differential equation' in problem_str:
        # Parse the equation
        expr, x = symbols('y'), symbols('x')
        y = sympy.Function('y')(x)
        eq = sympy.Eq(sympy.diff(y, x, x) + 2*sympy.diff(y, x) + 5*y, 0)
        solutions = sympy.dsolve(eq)
        
    # Check if the problem is a partial differential equation with more than two variables
    elif 'wave equation' in problem_str:
        x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
        u = sympy.Function('u')(x, y, z, t)
        eq = Eq(sympy.diff(u, t, t) - sympy.diff(u, x, x) - sympy.diff(u, y, y) - sympy.diff(u, z, z), 0)
        solutions = sympy.pde.pdsolve(eq)
        
    elif 'plot' in problem_str:
        # Parse the function and plot
        expr = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(problem_str.replace('plot ', ''))
        p = plot(expr, show=False)
        p.show()
        return "Graph displayed."
        
    elif 'numeric' in problem_str:
        # Parse the function, convert to a lambda function, and evaluate numerically
        expr = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(problem_str.replace('numeric ', ''))
        f = lambdify(x, expr)
        a, b = [float(x) for x in input("Enter the start and end points: ").split()]
        n = int(input("Enter the number of steps: "))
        x_vals = [a + i*(b-a)/n for i in range(n+1)]
        y_vals = [f(x) for x in x_vals]
        p = plot(expr, (x, a, b), show=False)
        p.scatter(x_vals, y_vals)
        p.show()
        return "Graph displayed."
    else:
        pass


    # Store the solution in the previous problems dictionary
    prev_problems[problem_str] = solutions

    # Return the solution(s) to the user
    return solutions
    
    
@app.route('/result')
def result():
    problem = request.args.get('problem')
    explanation = solve_problem(problem)
    return render_template('results.html', problem=problem, explanation=explanation)
   
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


results.html


        <h1>Math Problem Solver</h1>
        {% if explanation %}
            <p>{{ explanation }}</p>
        {% else %}
            <p>No solution found.</p>
        {% endif 

index.html


    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <label for="problem">Enter a math problem:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="problem" name="problem"><br><br>
        <button type="submit">Solve</button>
    </form>
```

I have already tried testing the solve_problem function without the gui implementation , it is working fine providing the write answers, but I just can't get it to work on gui version.

I am sorry if this sounds like an easy issue but I would appreciate any input as someone who is still learning.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you update your question with the error you see in the console?

Comment: I just added two images , one is the output of results.html and the other is the debug(console) output. The console doesn't show any error, I think the issue might be with my syntax or indentation but I have been going through the code over and over again, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Does your code ever call solve_problem()? It looks like your index.html form posts pack to your `index` function, which then simply calls `return render_template('results.html')` without including the explanation. You also have a /result route, but I don't think that is called either.

Perhaps you want to change your /index route similar to:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        problem = request.form['problem']
        explanation = solve_problem(problem)
        return render_template('results.html', explanation=explanation, problem=problem)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
```